# Setting the background image of a div using an image var?

Tags: jquery, set, background-image

Can anyone suggest how I could do this:
Using an image variable I want to set the background of a div, although not using the image's source/url. For example, this doesn't work:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
   $('#div').css("background-image", img);
}
img.src = "http://example.com/image.jpg";
```

Basically, I'm trying to set the width/height of the background image so it fits the div nicely. I figured using an image variable was the only way, but if it isn't, please suggest how I can do it. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create an absolutely positioned img and then using the image attributes set the width and height.  By absolutely positioning it you can have it displayed behind other content.

Give it a try and if you are having trouble with it, provide a code snippet and I can assist you in getting the html and css correct.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use an image object, just set it as a string. e.g.

```
var src = 'http://example.com/image.jpg';

$('#div').css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');
```

Remember to add in the URL bit ;)

Hope that helps :)

**Edit**

Sorry, I've just realised you were using an image object to preload it... In that case though, this:

```
var src = 'http://example.com/image.jpg';

$('<img/>').load(function(){

    $('#div').css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');

}).attr("src",src);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: `.src(src);` -> `.attr("src",src);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
   $('#div').css("background-image", "url(" + img.src + ")");
}
img.src = "http://example.com/image.jpg";
```

Additionally, onload isn't always enough for image preloading if the image is cached, it may not fire a load event.

```
var img = new Image();
function imgLoaded() {
  $('#div').css("background-image", "url(" + img.src + ")");
}
img.onload = imgLoaded;
img.src = "http://example.com/image.jpg";
if (img.complete || img.readystate === 4) {
  imgLoaded();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot set width / height of the background image. The only way to do that is using `background-size` property in CSS3 or use a absolute positioned image behind the content of the div.